# Why isn't CSS being applied within my UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview

When I try to display a local HTML page un a UIWebView, the CSS for that page is not being applied.  However, when I load that same page in the regular Safari, it is.  What could be causing this?

Comment: @user239393 If there is anything I can add to my answer to clarify.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [loadHTMLString](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:) to populate the content of the *UIWebView*? Is your CSS embedded in the HTML that you are loading into the view? If it references a file online, check that the URL file is the full path (not just the relative path).

If the CSS is referenced using a relative path it will work fine in the browser, but not in a *UIWebView* with statically loaded content.